# Prove continuity of $T(\varphi)=\int_\Omega f\varphi +\int_{\partial \Omega } g\varphi$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ open, smooth and bounded. Let  $f\in L^2(\Omega )$ and $g\in H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega )$. Prove that $$T(\varphi)=\int_\Omega f\varphi +\int_{\partial \Omega } g\varphi,\quad \varphi\in H^1(\Omega )$$
is continuous.

So $$|T(\varphi)|\leq \|f\|_{L^2}\underbrace{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}_{\leq \|\varphi\|_{H^1}}+\|g\|_{H^{-1/2}}\|\varphi\|_{H^{1/2}}\leq K\|\varphi\|_{H^1}+\|g\|_{H^{-1/2}}\|\varphi\|_{H^{1/2}}.$$
Now, do I have a theorem that tell me that $\|\varphi\|_{H^{1/2}}\leq C\|\varphi\|_{H^1}$ for a certain constant $C>0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The trace is continuous $H^1(\Omega )\longrightarrow H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega )$.